# yii2 validate related models

Tags: yii2, yii2-validation

We have 2 models:

- Order
- OrderItems

So when saving the related OrderItems I need to check some attributes from the parent Order.

Order has attributes: "time_begin" and "time_end" and OrderItem has its own "time_begin" and "time_end". So the rule is that times of the OrderItem must be between times of the parent Order.

For example, I have the following situation:

- user changes the "time_end" of the Order to the bigger value and changes the "time_end" of OrderItem to bigger value too
- try to save all the related data (Order and all its Items)
- Order validations pass successfully
- but when the OrderItem trying to validate its "time_end", it takes the old value of Order->time_end property and gives an validation error!!!

Any solution???
How to let OrderItem to know that Order has changed?

Comment: Just need to create your own validator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a complicated issue, you may consider this way:
- Don't call Order::validate() and OrderItems::validate() simultaneously.
- Order::validate() -> Order::save() first than OrderItems::validate() -> OrderItems::save() (is this failed, remember to revert Order if needed)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
We thought about that, maybe it's the only one decision...
We even use transaction to save related model, so we can roll back if something went wrong in OrderItems::validate() or save()